# Cocoapods - Master repository Disaster Recovery strategy

Tags: cocoapods

My company has been using `Cocoapods` in order to distribute our open source libraries. Me and my colleagues have been discussing disaster recovery and are wondering what would happen if the Cocoapods Master repository (located at https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) was to get lost?

Is there like a backup of that master repository that can be relied upon in case of major incident?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, there seem to be 8500 forks of it on Github and you can have one too in case Github is down! :)

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
```

There is probably a configuration variable you can use to tell CocoaPods to use your local clone.